# huffman encoding

Tags: c++, compression, huffman-code

I am trying to implement the huffman algorithm for compression, which requires writing bits of variable length to a file. Is there any way in C++ to write variable length data with 1-bit granularity to a file?

Answer (score 9):

No, the smallest amount of data you can write to a file is one byte.

You can use a [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) to make manipulating bits easier, then use an [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files.html) to write to file.  If you don't want to use bitset, you can use the [bitwise operators](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/38-bitwise-operators/) to manipulate your data before saving it.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest amount of bits you can access and save is 8 = 1 byte. You can access bits in byte using bit operators ^ & |.

You can set n'th bit to 1 using:

```
my_byte = my_byte | (1 << n);
```

where n is 0 to 7.

You can set n'th bit to 0 using:

```
my_byte = my_byte & ((~1) << n);
```

You can toggle n'th bit using:

```
my_byte = my_byte ^ (1 << n);
```

More details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_operators).

Answer (score 2):

klew's answer is probably the one you want, but just to add something to what Bill said, the Boost libraries have a [dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)  that I found helpful in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

All the info you need on bit twiddling is here:
[How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c)

But the smallest object that you can put in a file is a byte.
I would use dynamic_bitset and every time the size got bigger than 8 extract the bottom 8 bits into a char and write this to a file, then shift the remaining bits down 8 places (repeat).

Answer (score 1):

No. You will have to pack bytes. Accordingly, you will need a header in your file that specifies how many elements are in your file, because you are likely to have trailing bits that are unused.

Comment: you don't necessary have to count the number of elements of the file a eof special character may fits the bill